# Reproduce boxplot with only data points at given quantiles

Tags: boxplot

It is trivial to create a boxplot in R with a full dataset. However, with limited access to the whole dataset, I just have 5 data point at min, 25%, 50% ,75%, and max. So is there any easy way to reproduce the boxplot with only these 5 values?

Comment: What about `boxplot(your.five.data.points)`?

Answer (score 8):

It's still pretty trivial. You can't reproduce the whiskers of a default boxplot effectively if the minimum and maximum values exceed Tukey's fences, but the box itself should remain unaltered. E.g., with `x=rnorm(9999)`, compare `boxplot(x)` vs. `boxplot(quantile(x))`:

[image] $\leftarrow$ full dataset vs. your five values $\rightarrow$ [image]

Comment: `boxplot(fivenum(x))` is a lot shorter than `boxplot(c(min(x),quantile(x,c(.25,.5,.75)),max(x)))` (though if the quartiles don't match the definition of hinge in `fivenum` that might not be suitable)

Comment: Slick! Updated.

Comment: See the edit to my comment; your original has the advantage of being able to use any of the 9 definitions of quantiles. Then again, `boxplot(quantile(x))` would work in place of fivenum and probably matches the original post better; I'm just used to associating boxplots with fivenum.

Comment: Wow. Never knew that one either! We'll go with that one then.

Comment: Yep. In large samples like that you can't see any difference between them, of course